# How can i add some file as a resource into an existing assembly

Tags: c#

I have have to add several files into resources of an existing exe. I've tried to add resources by using ResourceWriter, but as far as i understood it creates a resource file (well at least exe becames not executable after ResourceWriter).

How can i add a file into an existing executable?

Comment: Classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/245360).

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why not put it in at compile time?

Comment: I'm making a bootstrapper, which should execute installation. Our installer has a specific structure, and now i have to implement solution, to allow us to build a web-installer (it have to be single executable).

Each time a new product will be build, it has different configuration and differenc content, but the bootstrapper is always the same.

Comment: But why not package it in the assembly itself and compile it for X versions?

Comment: In common case, user, who builds a new product, does not have Visual Studio and does not have access to source code of the bootstrapper. So bootstrapper should be "filled" while product building (creating of an installer)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, i've found [Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) and it seems to be the right assembly for me.